# Why does the list not properly render in a quotation?

Tags: support, formatting

Please see my answer here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/360783/45492. There I quote a Support article, however, the list is not rendered correctly in the quotation (see 1. below). I tried adding spaces and paragraphs to no avail. Am I doing something wrong?

> ## Reset using your Recovery Key (FileVault must be on)
>
> If FileVault is turned on and you have a FileVault [Recovery Key][2], you can use that key to reset your password.
>
> 1 .At the login screen, keep entering a password until you see a message saying that you can reset your password using your Recovery Key. If you don't see the message after three attempts, FileVault isn't on.
>
> 2. Click <kbd>></kbd>  next to the message. The password field changes to a Recovery Key field.
> 3. Enter your Recovery Key. Use uppercase characters, and include the hyphens.
>
> ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed :-) The rendering is a bit picky regarding the placing of `.` and space characters in quoted lists. See the [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/360783/revisions) for the specific change required (well, actually, I only changed one character at item 1 and 4).

Comment: Oh no - I should have seen that. Thanks!